Making configuration name customizable
I'm using Hydra to create some configuration of layers in my neural network, these layers will then be used in other configs to create neural network architectures. However, I find myself creating multiple repeated configs, and the only difference between them for example is the width.
An example of a layer config is the following:
diffusion128|gcn128|concurent:
  name: ProteinEncoder
  instanciate:
    _target_: atomsurf.networks.ProteinEncoderBlock
  kwargs:
    surface_encoder:
      name: DiffusionNetBlockBatch
      instanciate:
        _target_: atomsurf.network_utils.DiffusionNetBlockBatch  # diffusion_net.DiffusionNet
      kwargs:
        C_width: 128
        mlp_hidden_dims: [128, 128]
        dropout: 0.0
        use_bn: true
        init_time: 2.0  # either null (for constant init) or a float
        init_std: 2.0
    graph_encoder:
      name: GCNx2Block
      instanciate:
        _target_: atomsurf.network_utils.GCNx2Block
      kwargs:
        dim_in: 128
        hidden_dims: 128
        dim_out: 128
        dropout: 0.0
        use_bn: true
        use_weighted_edge_distance: false
    communication_block:
      name: ConcurrentCommunication
[....]

Is there a way to make the layer names customizable in the configuration? For example, changing diffusion128|gcn128|concurrent to diffusion{$width1}|gcn{$width2}|concurrent with width1 and width2 as parameters that can be defined when creating an architecture.

You can't use interpolation in keys.
However, if the main parameterization is for width, you can refactor your config to be something like:
width: 128
encoder:
  name: ProteinEncoder_${width}
  instanciate:
    _target_: atomsurf.networks.ProteinEncoderBlock
  kwargs:
    surface_encoder:
      name: DiffusionNetBlockBatch
      instanciate:
        _target_: atomsurf.network_utils.DiffusionNetBlockBatch  # diffusion_net.DiffusionNet
      kwargs:
        C_width: ${width}
        mlp_hidden_dims: [${width}, ${width}]
        dropout: 0.0
        use_bn: true
        init_time: 2.0  # either null (for constant init) or a float
        init_std: 2.0
    graph_encoder:
      name: GCNx2Block
      instanciate:
        _target_: atomsurf.network_utils.GCNx2Block
      kwargs:
        dim_in: ${width}
        hidden_dims: ${width}
        dim_out: ${width}
        dropout: 0.0
        use_bn: true
        use_weighted_edge_distance: false
    communication_block:
      name: ConcurrentCommunication

In fact, you can also use relative interpolation to make this relocatable:
encoder:
  name: ProteinEncoder_${.width}
  width: 128
  instanciate:
    _target_: atomsurf.networks.ProteinEncoderBlock
  kwargs:
    surface_encoder:
      name: DiffusionNetBlockBatch
      instanciate:
        _target_: atomsurf.network_utils.DiffusionNetBlockBatch
      kwargs:
        C_width: ${width}
        mlp_hidden_dims: [${...width}, ${...width}]
        dropout: 0.0
        use_bn: true
        init_time: 2.0  # either null (for constant init) or a float
        init_std: 2.0
    graph_encoder:
      name: GCNx2Block
      instanciate:
        _target_: atomsurf.network_utils.GCNx2Block
      kwargs:
        dim_in: ${..width}
        hidden_dims: ${..width}
        dim_out: ${..width}
        dropout: 0.0
        use_bn: true
        use_weighted_edge_distance: false
    communication_block:
      name: ConcurrentCommunication


thank you for your response. In your example, we will define only one encoder, so the blocks inside it are fixed, but in my case, diffusion{$width1}|gcn{$width2}|concurrent, in addition to the width, also the other encoders can change (diffusion, gcn, etc), how to define multiple encoders that have the width as parameters in your example

If the width is defined outside of the encoder. You can do something with config composition (defaults list) to build the config tree and have it all use interpolation to the width defined at the top level of the config.
